# Magento 2 Admin panel - Cart Price Rule view hangs (spinning wheel), JS Error

Tags: magento2, javascript, shopping-cart-price-rules, admin-panel, http-error-500

How do I resolve this issue? The Marketing -> Cart Price Rules keeps spinning and not loading. Following is the error message from chrome
   [image]

```
/pub/static/version1544579836/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_SalesRule/js/form/element/coupon-type.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
    /pub/static/version1544579836/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_SalesRule/js/form/element/manage-coupon-codes.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
    /pub/static/version1544579836/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/form/element/single-checkbox-toggle-notice.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
    console-output-handler.js:34 [2018-12-20 09:32:29] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_SalesRule/js/form/element/coupon-type" component.
    ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
    console-output-handler.js:34 [2018-12-20 09:32:29] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_SalesRule/js/form/element/manage-coupon-codes" component.
    ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
    console-output-handler.js:34 [2018-12-20 09:32:29] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/single-checkbox-toggle-notice" component.
    ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
    /pub/static/version1544579836/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/templates/form/element/helper/tooltip.html:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
    console-output-handler.js:34 [2018-12-20 09:32:29] [ERROR] Failed to load the "ui/form/element/helper/tooltip" template requested by "sales_rule_form.sales_rule_form.rule_information.website_ids".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can try to remove static content and then try static Content Deploy as describe below.

> 1) Set Magento 2 developer mode.

```
sudo php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

> 2) Remove Static Content for adminhtml.

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml/*
```

> 3) try forced Content Deploy

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

> 4) Give permission to pub, var, generated

```
sudo chmod -Rv 777 pub var generated
```

Comment: thank you, i will give it a try and report back!

Comment: @Ashish Viradiya  Welcome.